# nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect not working on custom port

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect` in my ingress rule to force http to https. If I leave nginx at the default 80/443 this works correctly, but if I'm using custom ports (8080, 8443), the redirect on 8080 still goes to 443.

I'm not seeing anything in the docs about specifying the redirect port. My overrides for nginx are:

```
controller:
  service:
    ports:
      http: 8080
      https: 8443
```

Comment: Can you refer to this [Force Redirect From HTTP to HTTPs On A Custom Port in Nginx](https://ma.ttias.be/force-redirect-http-https-custom-port-nginx/)Blog by Mattias Geniar and this [blog](https://vegastack.com/tutorials/redirect-http-to-https-in-nginx/#:~:text=return%20301%20https%3A%2F%2F%24host%24request_uri%20%2D%20Redirect,%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpage2%20.) by Shweta Singh & Sumit Patel. As per this blog, Nginx will emit [non-standard error code](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#errors) 497 which could be processed with an error_page directive.

Comment: Following this blogs and implementing this will resolve your issue.

Comment: @HemanthKumar isn't that for nginx rather then ingress-nginx? Doesn't seem like we can write those server {} blocks in ingress-nginx?

Comment: Seems to be this is the only possible way i can see and have a check if this can be write to ingress-nginx by using any converters.